# Young adult/children's TV series where a character's memories of a sporting loss are 'corrupted' into a win

Tags: story-identification

The series was sci-fi, possibly on ITV between 2000-2001.

There's only scene I remember was dark,  in a warehouse or storage facility with metal standalone shelves. The main characters were either on the run or invading enemy territory.

They had to retrieve someone's memory with an experimental procedure, to crack a code or to exact capture. Prior to this the subject (adult)  told the protagonist (teenager) about his attendance at a [football](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football) match where his team (Newcastle) lost,  but it was still his happiest memory to have seen them play. After the experimental procedure to retrieve his memory he remembered it as his team winning.

What was this show?

Comment: I've looked through a list of CITV shows and the only ones that stands out are these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_Force_(TV_series) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Wave

Comment: Only partial help I'm afraid, but I've seen 6 episodes of Delta Wave (only ten were ever made), and this scene didn't appear in them.